# if you compressed file containing random numbers it get bigger

Tags: c#, .net, random, compression

[image]

```
var file = new FileStream("random.txt", FileMode.Create);
var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
{
     var bytesToWrite = BitConverter.GetBytes(random.Next(int.MaxValue));
     file.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
}
file.Close();
```

when you simply add some random number to text file 
then compressed it get bigger, or it will remain as the same size as the text one

any one know **how** or **why** this happened?

Comment: extra overhead combined with bad compression technique?

Comment: You can't losslessly compress random data. Compression works by eliminating redundant data from the file (as identified through patterns); in the case of randomness, no data is redundant.

Comment: Why? Because you given it the absolute (or close to it) worse-case scenario for compression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Text files tend to compress nicely because they use the same data over and over. Adding some random numbers to the file makes the file less regular, so most compression algorithms will have a harder time compressing the file as much.

Read up on compression algorithms for a better understanding of this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_compression

Answer (score 5):

Compression algorithms dont promise you that it will get smaller.

The reason is just simple, there aren't enough unique values it can generate that are smaller.
Example:

If you have a 10 bit world, there are 2^10 values you can generate. Lets assume you could compress them all. But if you remove a bit you have only 2^9 values you can hold. So there are a lot of the original values that would never be able to be compressed correctly, and decompress back to the original value.

So most of the compression algorithms take in consideration that normal data isn't random, and is repeatative, or has some basic rule behind it.
Like texts only have a certain amount of characters used, so you can compress them pretty well.

Answer (score 1):

Well, what you generate is random binary file. Of course WinRar has difficulties to compress it.

If you save file as txt one with numbers as text you will see that there is room for compression.

```
    var file = File.CreateText("random.txt");
    var random = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        file.Write(random.Next());
    }
    file.Close();
```

Comment: You have room for compression that you have gained by changing the format of your data, I bet the final size will be larger than the original binary file.

Comment: Of course text file got bigger. But compression ratio was ~40%. My point was just to make sure that there is no confusion between binary and text files. (I don't know which sense it makes to name file with *.txt and push binary stuff there).

Answer (score 1):

an interesting article I found:

http://matt.might.net/articles/why-infinite-or-guaranteed-file-compression-is-impossible/

Also I remember sometime ago reading about a patent that was granted based on the claim of a compression algorithm that guaranteed that the output was never bigger than the input... I have not been able to find the same article but I have found this one that is even more challenging:

http://gailly.net/05533051.html

Enjoy the reading

Answer (score 0):

If the byte order is truly random then you won't notice any change in size. There are even instances where a rar file can be larger than the files it contains (I assume because some of the overhead from the headers in the rar container).

Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression